# jQuery select made with unordered list not clicking

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I´m using an unordered list to replace the select function. I have a state and city combo where I choose the state and then it auto complete the city. A traditional select for registration.

The problem is that I´m able to do the jSon stuff, but when I load the < li > into the cities I´m not able to get the click. I will show the code:

```
$('ul#states li a').click(function() {

    var uf = $(this).find('span.value').html();

    var $comboCidades = $('ul#cities');
    if (uf == 0) {
        //$comboCidades.html('<a href="javascript:;"><span>Selecione</span></a>');
        return;
    }
    $.getJSON('/contato/cidades/', { uf: uf }, function(data) {
        var options = ''; 
        var dataLength = data.length;
        for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
            options += '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">'+data[i]['nome']+'<span class="value" style="display:none">'+data[i]['id']+'</span></a></li>';
        }   
        $comboCidades.html(options);
    });         

});
```

That´s the Jquery code, I request /contato/cidades/ that Return´s to me a enconded json with all the cities, it works perfect.

So, I populate a < ul > tag with the command $comboCidades.html(options); and IT WORKS, I can have the < ul > with all the cities separated by < li >, the problem is, that I´m not able to select the cities < li >, it did not get the values, but, if I add a < li > without being loaded by json, it can get the value from the li.

Is there any problem loading < li > with jquery and html() that it´s not a real < li >? Can I fix it with some kind of jQuery functions?!

MY HTML CODE:

```
<div class="input">
    <label>Cidade:</label>
    <div class="select">
        <p><a href="javascript:;"><span>Selecione</span></a></p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:;">Santa Catarina</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're assigning the `click` event for the elements under `#cities` when the page loads.

Problem is that if those elements don't exist when page loads, they don't get the event.

Try using `.live()` instead:

```
$('ul#cities li a').live('click', function() {...
```

Or better, use `.delegate()` if you have jQuery 1.4 or later.

```
$('ul#cities').delegate('li a', 'click', function() {...
```

This places the handler on `ul#cities` so as long as it exists when the page loads, the handler will be there for you. (Similar to `live()` which places the handler higher up the DOM.)

*Side note, when you're referencing an ID, `$('#cities')` is a little better than `$('ul#cities')`.*

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot, very helpful your question. I´m using the jquery min by google, 1.4 and will try with delegate, I just can test it in one hour than I came back here and reply.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot and congratulations for the good and quality contribution high level you have. Best regard´s.